# Anaconda's auto-complete does not work for tensorflow

Tags: python, autocomplete, tensorflow, sublimetext3

Look,I am tring to build a Python IDE base on Ubuntu16.04,and sublime Text 3 is my chioce.
Anaconda was installed via Package Control.meanwhile,it's auto-complete works fine for the original module of Python3,but not for tensorflw.

python3.sublime-build(created by myself):

```
{ "cmd": ["/usr/bin/python3", "-u", "$file"],
 "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)", "selector": "source.python"
}
```

So,how to make Anaconda's auto-complete works for third module,i.e. tensorflow in this case.
btw,I suppose the reason is, that Anaconda does not parse the third libraries and directories to lookup my code and complete it.

Any suggestion will be appreciate.Thanka a lot!

appended:

```
chuchienshu@chuchienshu-virtual-machine:~$ ll /usr/lib/python3.5/
total 4500
drwxr-xr-x  34 root        root          4096 5月  18 12:36 ./
drwxrwxrwx 140 root        root          4096 5月  11 23:18 ../
-rw-r--r--   1 root        root          8628 11月 18 03:19 abc.py
-rw-r--r--   1 root        root         31578 11月 18 03:19 aifc.py
-rw-r--r--   1 root        root           475 11月 18 03:19 antigravity.py
-rw-r--r--   1 root        root         90323 11月 18 03:19 argparse.py
-rw-r--r--   1 root        root         12001 11月 18 03:19 ast.py
-rw-r--r--   1 root        root         11971 11月 18 03:19 asynchat.py
drwxr-xr-x   3 root        root          4096 2月  16 04:21 asyncio/
-rw-r--r--   1 root        root         20104 11月 18 03:19 asyncore.py
........
chuchienshu@chuchienshu-virtual-machine:~$ ll /home/chuchienshu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/
appdirs-1.4.3.dist-info/        pyparsing-2.2.0.dist-info/
appdirs.py                      pyparsing.py
easy_install.py                 setuptools/
external/                       setuptools-35.0.2.dist-info/
google/                         six-1.10.0.dist-info/
numpy/                          six.py
numpy-1.12.1.dist-info/         tensorflow/
packaging/                      tensorflow-1.1.0.dist-info/
packaging-16.8.dist-info/       werkzeug/
pkg_resources/                  Werkzeug-0.12.1.dist-info/
protobuf-3.3.0.dist-info/       wheel/
protobuf-3.3.0-py3.5-nspkg.pth  wheel-0.29.0.dist-info/
```

Comment: are you talking about IPython auto-complete?

Comment: if you create a simple script with one function eg:  `def foo(val):  print(val)` and import it, does auto-complete show "foo"?

Comment: I did what you advice,and it works well.Is it a class library path problem?Some related information were added on the post above.Thanks!

Comment: the path of TensorFlow was auto-created by command, sudo pip3 install tensorflow.

Answer (score 0):

Anaconda has it's own package manager.  Try this out from the command line

```
conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow=1.0.0
```

Here is a list of the other versions that conda has available. https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/tensorflow/files

ref: https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/tensorflow